# Unicode in Erlang logs with logger

Tags: unicode, erlang

I’m trying to output some Unicode into log with:

```
logger:debug("~ts", [<<"Тест"/utf8>>]).
```

and getting the following in log:

```
DEFAULT FORMATTER CRASHEDDEFAULT FORMATTER CRASHEDDEFAULT FORMATTER....
```

However, if I use `~s` as a format string instead, it doesn’t crash, but outputs non-unicode version:

```
debug: Ð¢ÐµÑ<U+0081>Ñ<U+0082>
```

Any ideas? Can’t seem to find what am I doing wrong.

**Environment**

`Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.0.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]`

**Logger config from `sys.config`:**

```
{kernel, [
  {logger, [
    {handler, default, logger_std_h,
      #{level => debug,
        formatter => {logger_formatter, #{single_line => true}},
        config => #{type => {file, "log/main.log"}}}},
    {handler, errors, logger_std_h,
      #{level => error,
        formatter => {logger_formatter, #{single_line => false}},
        config => #{type => {file, "log/errors.log"}}}}
  ]},
  {logger_level, debug}
]}
```

Comment: Does it work with `io:format("~ts", [<<"Тест"/utf8>>]).` ?

Comment: It actually does. I spent whole night tracing with someone on Erlang Slack channel and we found that it is single line formatter specifically that had a bug crashing the whole thing. It's now fixed in 21.1. After upgrading the issue's gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent whole night tracing with someone on Erlang Slack channel and we found that it is single line formatter specifically that had a bug crashing the whole thing. It's now fixed in 21.1. After upgrading the issue's gone.